# nLog: Filter or remove message

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

How do I filter or remove unwanted message from Info level log?
Here is the my result of the logs.

**Log Result**

[image]

I only want to log the yellow color only. But whatever I try, I cannot remove the extra log before and after the yellow color above. Here is my code.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("--- THIS IS MY MESSAGE ---");
    return View();
}
```

**nlog.config**

```
  ...
<target xsi:type="File" name="activityLog" fileName="${gdc:item=appbasepath}\Logs\log-activity-${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${uppercase:${level}}|${message:raw=true}" />
  ...
<logger name="*" level="Info" writeTo="activityLog" />
  ...
```

Comment: Add `${logger}` to the File-Target-Layout, to see logger-names. Then you can use wildcards to perform filtering of logevents from unwanted loggers. https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a rule to throw away the extra messages

```
<rules>
   <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

   <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
   <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxLevel="Info" final="true" /> <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />
</rules>
```

[NLog Wiki - Getting Started](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-(project.json))

Comment: My mistakes. I put the code but the sequence is wrong.Thanks for it. :-)